# fetching songs from sd card crashes

Tags: android

I used one topics for finding mp3s from sd card and showing in a listview.
I edited the code but it has some problems. when it launches, it crashes.

I have a MainActivity like this:

```
package ir.shakhsii.readingfromsd;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private Button btnPlay;

    private Button btnPlaylist;

    private SeekBar songProgressBar;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private TextView songTitleLabel;

    // Media Player
    private  MediaPlayer mp;
    private SongsManager songManager;
    private int currentSongIndex = 0; 
    private boolean isShuffle = false;
    private boolean isRepeat = false;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);

        // All player buttons
        btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnPlaylist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);
        songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle2);


        // Mediaplayer
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        songManager = new SongsManager();


        // Listeners
        songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

        // Getting all songs list
        songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

        // By default play first song
        playSong(0);

        /**
         * Play button click event
         * plays a song and changes button to pause image
         * pauses a song and changes button to play image
         * */
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check for already playing
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.pause();
                        // Changing button image to play button

                    }
                }else{
                    // Resume song
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button

                    }
                }

            }
        });






        /**
         * Button Click event for Play list click event
         * Launches list activity which displays list of songs
         * */
        btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayListActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);         
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Receiving song index from playlist view
     * and play the song
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                     int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == 100){
             currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
             // play selected song
             playSong(currentSongIndex);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to play a song
     * @param songIndex - index of song
     * */
    public void  playSong(int songIndex){
        // Play song
        mp.reset();
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();

    }







    /**
     * 
     * */
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

    }



    /**
     * On Song Playing completed
     * if repeat is ON play same song again
     * if shuffle is ON play random song
     * */
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

        // check for repeat is ON or OFF
        if(isRepeat){
            // repeat is on play same song again
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        } else if(isShuffle){
            // shuffle is on - play a random song
            Random rand = new Random();
            currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        } else{
            // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
            if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            }else{
                // play first song
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
     public void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
     }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

and I have a playListActivity like this:

```
    package ir.shakhsii.readingfromsd;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

    public class PlayListActivity extends ListActivity {
    // Songs list
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,   String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
        // get all songs from sdcard
        this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

        // looping through playlist
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsListData.add(song);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
                R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.songTitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();
        // listening to single listitem click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting listitem index
                int songIndex = position;

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
                in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
                setResult(100, in);
                // Closing PlayListView
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and I have a songsManager like so:

```
package ir.shakhsii.readingfromsd;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path
    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }
}
```

and I have the obvious XML files which contains a button for playlist and some buttons for playing a song.
please help me with my code. what is wrong with it?

Comment: Post the logcat. Tell when it crashes. Tell on which statement it crashes.

Comment: You cannot play song 0 when there are no mp3 files found as the list will be empty then. You should check that before you try to play a song.

Comment: I connect my phone so it should detect songs from my phone. I have crashes in songsManager at line [if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) { ] and in MainActivity at line [songsList = songManager.getPlayList();]!? I don't understand what should I do?

Comment: The LogCat tells you all. You  can see it. Post the LogCat so we can see it all. Please react better to  my comments. Is the list not empty? Ok then how many mp3's are found?

Comment: Do not  hardcode path  /sdcard/. And check if it exists with `home.exists()`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience . I'm new to android. I have NullPointerException! but I don't know where is the problem? Is the code fetching the songs right?

Comment: Your media path is wrong. Now did you add `if(!home.exists()) { ..errormessage. .}? You are still not reacting to my comments enough.

Comment: yes I added the code in the getPlayList class. it exists!

Comment: if home.listFiles() returns null your program will crash with a nullpointerexception if you determine the length on it with home.listFiles().length.

Comment: I have a NullPointerException as I said above. so what should I do?

Comment: Well you could check `if home.listFiles() returns null`.

Comment: I don't know how to do this! could you pleasing show me ?

Comment: if ( home.listFiles() == null ) { errormessage or error log and do not continue as that will crash}